# Pulling reports from Microsoft Sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting, ssms

I was wondering what is the process to be able to pull reports from a database. The company I work for uses EBIS which is a program for aviation repair stations. It stores everything to its own database on our server but the GUI doesn't really have good means to pull reports. I have some background in computers and have messed around with sql just as a hobby, so my company wants me to be the one to try and get these reports for them. I have access to the server through SSMS and can run queries on it. I just haven't had any experience pulling certain tables and export them to excel or just using SSMS for reporting. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you probably don't even have Reporting Services installed. When you say "reports" what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is a tool for both managing/configuring SQL Server instances and also querying the attached databases using SQL. If you know some SQL then you can write a query, execute it and return some results. The SSMS options allow you to configure how those results are returned in the application e.g. as a grid on-screen, as delimited text on-screen or saved to a file. You can save the query scripts to run them again at a later date, and if your SQL skills are up to it you can add parameters to your script to make it more re-usable.

However SSMS is *not* generally considered a reporting tool. What I am describing above is known as "ad-hoc" querying, which means this process is normally used to prototype a report or to get some data needed for a one-off purpose or that can't be obtain through an actual report. This may be enough for your initial needs however, but long-term you will want an actual reporting platform that enables you to publish your queries as reports that can be run by people without SQL skills, can be exported to various formats, can have charts or other visualisations added to them.

If you are using the SQL Server product then a natural option for you is SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). Without going into too much technical detail, this will allow you to take your SQL query and embed it in a report that can be run on a web-based platform by your users. You can control the design of the output in terms of tables, charts etc. There are other options instead of SSRS as well, that provide similar capability.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. What other options would you suggest besides SSRS?

Comment: If you want some other options, you may want to look into http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the following tutorial since it is updated and also provides you sample data and tables to play with :

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167305.aspx

Comment: That's a link to a Reporting Services tutorial, but I don't think that is what the OP is asking about (SSRS).

Comment: I used this tutorial when I needed to pull out few reports from MS Sql Server so I guess it could help OP